# customize the color of AnsiColorLogger in ant?

Tags: java, terminal, colors, ant

Currently my ant output is colorized by [`AnsiColorLogger`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#AnsiColorLogger). It works as expected, and now I want to customize the colors (default ones are too dim). I created a color file as specified, but have no idea how to pass the file name through. The documentation says

> This file must be specified as the value of a system variable named `ant.logger.defaults` and passed as an argument using the `-D` option to the **java** command that invokes the Ant application.

How to pass an argument to the java command if I just run on terminal with `ant`? I tried to pass

```
-Dant.logger.defaults=<my file path>
```

to `ant` but no luck. I also tried setting environment variable

```
ANT_OPTS='-Dant.logger.defaults=<my file path>'
```

but it didn't work either. In case it matters, I am with

- OS X 10.10.5
- Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6
- Java 1.8.0_65

Comment: in which directory is your file with custom colors?

Comment: @Willmore, thank you for the pointer. The directory is indeed the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my bug: my path to the file was `~/my-file` but `~` in single quotes is not expanded. That simple.

(I forgot the fact that when I use `~` in terminal, it is expanded by the shell before passed to the program.)

Answer (score 1):

Typical setup for ant:

```
export ANT_HOME="${HOME}/opt/apache-ant"
export ANT_ARGS="-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger"
export ANT_OPTS="-Dant.logger.defaults=${HOME}/etc/ant-colors.properties"
export PATH="${ANT_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

In this case I have ant installed in my home directory under `opt/`, while it's color configuration is similarly in the home directory under `etc/`. This can be customized to whatever it needs to be. Use of `${HOME}` avoids issues with `~`, as long as I also use double quotes as in the example instead of single quotes.

My initial error was that I thought the `-D` could be added with `ANT_ARGS`, but we need both `ANT_ARGS` and `ANT_OPTS` as above.

This is the `ant-colors.properties` I am using on macOs:

```
AnsiColorLogger.ERROR_COLOR=31
AnsiColorLogger.WARNING_COLOR=35
AnsiColorLogger.INFO_COLOR=36
AnsiColorLogger.VERBOSE_COLOR=32
AnsiColorLogger.DEBUG_COLOR=34
```

Note that I leave out the attribute prefix "2;", as that would but the output in Bold. I also do not use "1;", as then the output is way to light. Instead I leave it at the default which has ideal visibility to me.

Note the syntax is as follows:

```
AnsiColorLogger.*=Attribute;Foreground;Background
```

Comment: This was super helpful. I tried the ant plugin for oh-my-zsh and also found the colors way too dim. I added only the ANT_OPTS line to the .oh-my-zsh/plugins/ant/ant.plugins.zsh script and used your example ant-colors.properties file, and it looks great!